# Sending icmp packet with boost clears checksum bytes

Tags: c++, boost, ping, icmp

When sending an ICMPv6 echo request with Boost Asio, some layer appears to be clearing out the checksum whenever I do a send_to or async_send_to call.  When using the command line ping utility, there is no issue.  With any call, all of the fields: type, code, identifier, sequence and the payload are represented when I look at the outgoing packet in Wireshark.  Plus the correct bytes are in the buffer before and after the call.  Take a look at the picture here:

[Wireshark capture icmpv6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3f31.jpg)

Here's code to reproduce. This is Boost 1.62, VS2015.

```cpp
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::address_v6;
using boost::asio::ip::icmp;

const char* ICMPREQUESTBODY_ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwabcdefghi";
const unsigned short ICMPIDENTIFIER_ = 1;
unsigned short tempchecksum = 0x5d46;
unsigned int icmpsequence_ = 70;
unsigned char ICMPv6TYPEECHOREQUEST_ = 128;
unsigned char ICMPv6CODE_ = 0;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::io_service::work iowrk(io);
    boost::thread iothread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));

    auto source = address_v6::from_string("2601:XXX:XXX:XXX::106");
    auto destination = address_v6::from_string("2601:XXX:XXX:XXX::202");
    icmp::endpoint remote_endpoint = boost::asio::ip::icmp::endpoint(destination, 0);
    icmp::endpoint local_endpoint(icmp::v6(), 0);

    icmp::socket elsocko(io, local_endpoint);

    unsigned char icmppacket[40];
    icmppacket[0] = ICMPv6TYPEECHOREQUEST_;
    icmppacket[1] = ICMPv6CODE_;
    icmppacket[2] = (tempchecksum & 0xff00) >> 8;
    icmppacket[3] = (tempchecksum & 0x00ff);
    icmppacket[4] = (ICMPIDENTIFIER_ & 0xff00) >> 8;
    icmppacket[5] = (ICMPIDENTIFIER_ & 0x00ff);
    icmppacket[6] = (icmpsequence_ & 0xff00) >> 8;
    icmppacket[7] = (icmpsequence_ & 0x00ff);
    memcpy(&icmppacket[8], ICMPREQUESTBODY_, 32);

    elsocko.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(icmppacket), remote_endpoint);

    //boost::asio::streambuf reply_buffer_;
    //elsocko.receive_from(reply_buffer_.prepare(65535), remote_endpoint);
}
```

The destination does not respond because the checksum is invalid.  What can cause this / how can I fix it?

Comment: It might incorrectly believe that checksum is offloaded to the network card.  Would you happen to know what OS you are running?

Comment: @stark  I'm running Win 10 (10.0.14393).

Comment: @stark I put my demo app on a Win 2012R2 and it worked fine.  So you are on to something.  I don't see any settings on my local nic that stand out to indicate that it could be doing this.  I only see tcp and udp checksum offloads options..

Comment: I swapped nic on pc with an Intel GB and issue remains.  Tried on older Win10 in a virtual on another box and it pinged fine.

Comment: I disabled McAfee Firewall and this corrected the issue.  McAfee must be meddling here somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling McAfee LiveSafe Firewall allowed the icmpv6 ping to work.  There doesn't appear to be a setting that addresses this directly.